# Cannot assign char to char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is my code:

```
    printf("%s\n", "test1");
    char c = '2';
    char * lines[2];
    char * tmp1 = lines[0];

    *tmp1 = c;
    printf("%s\n", "test2");
```

I don't see the second `printf` in console.

**Question**: Can anybody explain me what's wrong with my code?

NOTE: I'm trying to learn `C` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
char * lines[2];
```

declares an array of two `char` pointers. However, you don't actually *initialize* the pointers to anything. So later when you do `*tmp1 = (char)c;` then you assign the character `c` to somewhere in memory, possibly even address zero (i.e. `NULL`) which is a bad thing.

The solution is to either create the array as an array of arrays, like

```
char lines[2][30];
```

This declares lines to have two arrays of 30 characters each, and since strings needs a special terminator character you can have string of up to 29 characters in them.

The second solution is to dynamically allocate memory for the strings:

```
char *lines[2];
lines[0] = malloc(30);
lines[1] = malloc(30);
```

Essentially this does the same as the above array-of-arrays declaration, but allocates the memory on the heap.

Of course, maybe you just wanted a single string of a single character (plus the terminator), then you were almost right, just remove the asterisk:

```
char line[2];  /* Array of two characters, or a string of length one */
```

Answer (score 3):

`lines` is uninitialized, and `tmp1` initialization is wrong.

It should be:

```
char lines[2];
char * tmp1 = lines;
```

Alternatively, you can say:

```
char * tmp1 = &lines[0];
```

Or else for an array of strings:

```
char lines[2][30];
char * tmp1 = lines[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

The array `lines` in uninitialized. Thus `lines[0]` is an uninitalized pointer. Dereferencing it in `*tmp1` is sheer **undefined behaviour**.

Here's an alternative, that may or may not correspond to what you want:

```
char lines[2];
char * tmp1 = lines;   // or "&lines[0]"

*tmp = c;
```

Or, more easily:

```
char lines[2] = { c, 0 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
char * lines[2];
```

creates an array of two char pointers. But that doesn't allocate memory, it's just a "handle" or "name" for the pointer in memory. The pointer doesn't point to something useful.

You will either have to allocate memory using `malloc()`:

```
char * lines = malloc(2);
```

or tell the compiler to allocate memory for you:

```
char lines[2];
```

Note: Don't forget to terminate the string with a `0` byte before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

`char *lines[2];` : A two element array of char pointers.

`char *tmp;`      : A pointer to a character.

`char *tmp = lines[0]` : The value inside the array element `0` of the `lines` array is transferred into `tmp`. Because it is an automatic array, therefore it will have garbage as the value for `lines[0]`.

`*temp`           : Dereference the garbage value. Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * tmp1 = lines[0];
```

here you declare a char pointer and initialize its pointer value to line[0],the fist element stored in line array which is also uninitialized.

now the tmp is pointing to somewhere unknown and not actually accessible. When you

```
*tmp1 = (char)c;
```

you are operating on a invalid memory address which causes a Segmentation fault.